# How to generate a temporary file for use in a unit test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, testunit

The method to test allows adding a `path` to additional files the user adds which contain data.

For example, the user might store a file called `data.txt` in the `/workspace/data` directory. And we want to add the path to this directory to an already existing array called `DATA_PATH`.

**Method:**

```
def add_custom_path(path)
  DATA_PATH.unshift(path)
end
```

Where `path` is a location in a Rails app where the user stores a file.

The gem uses `test-unit`.

**Question:**

Is there a way to temparily generate a file in some directory, run an `assert_not_empty` test, and then have the file disappear?

I don't have experience writing tests for gems so any guidance would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[The `.create` and `.new` methods of Ruby's `Tempfile` take a second argument which is the directory you want the file to be in](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html#method-c-create), and files created by `Tempfile` are automatically deleted when the temporary file's `File` object is garbage-collected or Ruby exits. So you can create a temporary file,

```
tempfile = Tempfile.new('filename', 'directoryname')
```

write to it, do your test and let Ruby clean it up for you.

Note that the first argument is not the entire unqualified name of the file, but a part to which `Tempfile` adds disambiguating characters, so you can safely do it more than once in a test suite.

Also, if you need the file to have a particular suffix, you can do e.g.

```
tempfile = Tempfile.new(['filename', '.rb'], 'directoryname')
```